# Conflict with modules uLogin and Profile 2

Tags: users

I use registration on my site for 3 types of roles by module [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2). Now i need use registration from social networks and i using [uLogin](https://www.drupal.org/project/ulogin) but after registration from social user isn't has role.
What could be the reason?